# How do i use NGINX to reverse proxy to local react app

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy

I'm trying to do a simple reverse proxy to my local react app with nginx. I can't wrap my head around how this works. Do i need a root variable in `location /test` or maybe a alias? because nginx is looking in the wrong address. (im running my react app locally at localhost:3001)

Already tried using `rewrite /test(.*) /$1 break` in the "location /test"-block

this is my nginx.conf:

```
server {
    listen 81 ;
    server_name app1.localhost;

    location / {  
        root   html;
        index  index.html index.htm;
    }
    location /test {
        proxy_pass   http://localhost:3001;
    }
}
```

heres the console log when i try to enter `app1.localhost:81/test`:
[image]

Comment: Why do you have two `location` blocks (or, asking differently, why don't you put the `proxy_pass` into the `/` location block)?

Comment: this is just an experiment, I want `/` to just show the default index.html file from nginx and `/test` to show my react app

Comment: The issue is that your react app is unaware of the fact that is it mounted under the `/test` base path. So you see requests being made like `/static/js/…` which actually would need to be `/test/static/js/…` in order to resolve correctly.

Comment: Hmm, so the static files of my react app have to be hosted from nginx too?

Comment: It'd be easiest if you'd just choose a specific `server_name` for your app exclusively and put the `proxy_pass` under `/`. You can still have the default nginx site.

Comment: How do i switch going from the default nginx site to my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just go with two `server` blocks:

```
server {
    listen 81 default_server;

    location / {  
        root html;
        index index.html index.htm;
    }
}

server {
    listen 81;
    server_name app1.localhost;

    location / {  
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
    }
}
```

Comment: That does work, but why cant I use the same server for both of the locations?

Comment: `location /test` means "everything that starts with /test". But your app includes links like `/static/js/…` that *don't* start with /test… You'd basically need to have your app run at http://localhost:3001/test to make this work.